# Populating textbox with contents of Arraylist c#

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I have a frustrating problem. With the following code in my clsExchange which is called in my FormExchange with simply `txtPhonesInSystem.Text = ClsExchange.listPhones();`I can only display the first arraylist entry.

```
 public string listPhones()
    {
        string strphone = string.Empty;

        foreach (clsPhone phone in phoneArray)
        {

            strphone = (strphone + phone.PhoneNumber.ToString() + "\n");
            return strphone;


        }
        return strphone;
    }
```

However, if i take the logic and put in in the btn_press event on the form.cs it displays the complete contents. The only difference I can see is instead of return strphone I use txtbox.Text=strphone. Any suggestions greatly appreciated aS I have been at this all day.

**EDIT**
Thankyou all for your answers. I new it had to be something as simple as that. I guess my brain isn't made right for this stuff. Shame because I love it.

Comment: You don't need the return strphone line in your foreach

Comment: You can also write the concat line more succintly: strphone += String.Format("{0}{1}", phone.PhoneNumber, Environment.NewLine);

Comment: Ah, I get what you mean, sorry. You can also then do (in the form load or similar) txtbox.Text = listPhones();

Comment: The "only difference" you can see is the is cause of the problem. [C# return keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line inside the `foreach` is the problem:

```
return strphone;
```

You're quitting on the first record.

As an aside, is this still C# 1.0?  If not, why are you using `ArrayLists`?

Comment: No, but doing it this simple way to get it working then planning on converting to hashtable so i can remove entries without upsetting the index.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `return` in the foreach loop which force to exit entire method at the first loop cycle so `strphone` contains only the first phome number.

If you are usign .NET 3 you can simplify solution using single LINQ query:

```
txtPhonesInSystem.Text = 
          phoneArray.Select(p => p.PhoneNumber)
                    .Aggregate((acc, next) => acc + "\n" + next);
```

otherwise just remove `return strphone;` line of code.

Also it makes sense using [Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) instead of hard coded `"\n"` value.